# This code returns distinct values. However, what I want is to return a strongly typed collection as opposed to an anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
var foo = (from data in pivotedData.AsEnumerable()
                   select new
                   {
                     Group = data.Field<string>("Group_Number"),
                     Study = data.Field<string>("Study_Name")
                   }).Distinct();
```

As expected this returns distinct values. However, what I want is to return a strongly-typed collection as opposed to an anonymous type, so when I do:

```
var foo = (from data in pivotedData.AsEnumerable()
                   select new BarObject
                   {
                     Group = data.Field<string>("Group_Number"),
                     Study = data.Field<string>("Study_Name")
                   }).Distinct();
```

This does not return the distinct values, it returns them all. Is there a way to do this with actual objects?

Comment: Implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` on your type.

Comment: @dlev what `GetHashCode` should do?

Comment: @BrunoLM: Read for example this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305324/why-use-gethashcode-over-equals/6305531#6305531 GetHashCode should deliver a hashcode over all fields that Equals also compares, and is used for hashtables or dictionaries for quick lookup of objects.

Comment: @Bruno Distinct will attempt to put each object into a hash table (and will return only those that do not already exist.) That means that hash code must be implemented properly to ensure that equal items have the same hash. Otherwise, `Equals()` (probably) won't be called, since the objects might hash to different buckets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `Distinct()` (and many other LINQ features) to work, the class being compared (`BarObject` in your example) must implement implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, or alternatively provide a separate `IEqualityComparer<T>` as an argument to `Distinct()`.

Many LINQ methods take advantage of `GetHashCode()` for performance because internally they will use things like a `Set<T>` to hold the unique items, which uses hashing for O(1) lookups.  Also, `GetHashCode()` can quickly tell you if two objects *may* be equivalent and which ones are definitely not - as long as `GetHashCode()` is properly implemented of course.

So you should make all your classes you intend to compare in LINQ implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` for completeness, or create a separate `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have done.  I take it that GetHashCode is more important if I am storing the objects in, for example, a dictionary?

Comment: @Darren: GetHashCode() is a very quick way of seeing if two objects MAY be equivalent.  This is because any two equivalent objects should always have the same hash code.  There's many LINQ methods that take advantage of the hash code for processing and internally use sets or dictionaries.  Thus, when using LINQ, both are important.

Comment: @Darren: Just decompiled Distinct() and it indeed does use a Set<TSource> internally which utilizes hashing.

Comment: @Darren: Look at the blog post, Gage has mentioned: http://blog.jordanterrell.com/post/LINQ-Distinct()-does-not-work-as-expected.aspx. ``Distinct`` *requires* ``GetHashCode`` to function correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `BarObject` because the [`EqualityComparer.Default<BarObject>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) is reference equality unless you have provided overrides of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` (this is what [`Enumerable.Distinct<BarObject>(this IEnumerable<BarObject> source)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) uses). Alternatively, you can pass in an `IEqualityComparer<BarObject>` to [`Enumerable.Distinct<BarObject>(this IEnumerable<BarObject>, IEqualityComparer<BarObject>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Either do as dlev suggested or use:

```
var foo = (from data in pivotedData.AsEnumerable()
               select new BarObject
               {
                 Group = data.Field<string>("Group_Number"),
                 Study = data.Field<string>("Study_Name")
               }).GroupBy(x=>x.Group).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault())
```

Check this out for more info http://blog.jordanterrell.com/post/LINQ-Distinct()-does-not-work-as-expected.aspx

Comment: Thats (in my opinion) not a very nice solution, as Distinct is much faster and is just designed to do what the op wants. The blog post, however, was interesting. Looks like I was right in assuming ``Distinct`` uses a ``HashSet<>`` internally.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `Distinct` can not compare your `BarObject` objects. Therefore it compares their references, which of course are all different from each other, even if they have the same contents.

So either you overwrite the `Equals` method, or you supply a custom EqualityComparer to `Distinct`. Remember to overwrite `GetHashCode` when you implement `Equals`, otherwise it will produce strange results if you put your objects for example into a dictionary or hashtable as key (e.g. `HashSet<BarObject>`). It might be (don't know exactly) that Distinct internally uses a hashset.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462451/gethashcode-guidelines-in-c) is a collection of good practices for `GetHashCode`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [other overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) for Distinct() that takes a comparer.  You can then implement your own [IEqualityComparer<BarObject>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var foo = (from data in pivotedData.AsEnumerable().Distinct()
                   select new BarObject
                   {
                     Group = data.Field<string>("Group_Number"),
                     Study = data.Field<string>("Study_Name")
                   });
```

Comment: That **may** be possible, but it has not the same semantics. If there are other fields besides 'Group' and 'Study' some duplicates might get left over.

Comment: Yes, there are other fields.  I ommitted them for brevity.  I did try this approach initially.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Should be as simple as:

```
var foo = (from data in pivotedData.AsEnumerable()
               select new
               {
                 Group = data.Field<string>("Group_Number"),
                 Study = data.Field<string>("Study_Name")
               }).Distinct().Select(x => new BarObject {
                 Group = x.Group,
                 Study = x.Study
               });
```