# Linq Distinct not being very Distinct

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Is this linq statement correct for getting unique values of 'Name' from my newSpecs collection?

distinctSpecialties is showing duplicates.

```
IEnumerable<SpecialtyData> distinctSpecialties = newSpecs
    .Select(s => s).Distinct()
    .OrderBy(s => s.Name);
```

Comment: How is equality defined for `SpecialtyData`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking about *getting unique values of 'Name' from my newSpecs collection*, but your code returns `IEnumerable<SpecialtyData>`. Something is wrong: either the question or the return type.

If you need only names, you need `IEnumerable<string>` instead:

```
IEnumerable<string> distinctNames = newSpecs
    .Select(s => s.Name)
    .Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
```

If you need entire `SpecialtyData` instances, you can either use `GroupBy`+`First`:

```
IEnumerable<SpecialtyData> distinctSpecialties = newSpecs
    .GroupBy(s => s.Name)
    .Select(g=> g.First())
```

or override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods within `SpecialtyData` class to make `Distinct` work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define "distinct" - by default reference types are distinct if they are separate instances (ReferenceEquals).  You can override the default by either:

- Implementing `IEquatable<SpecialtyData>` in `SpecialtyData`
- Overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `SpecialtyData`
- defining an `IEqualityComparer<SpecialtyData>` and passing that to `Distinct`

A simpler way to get the "first" distinct item by name is to use `GroupBy`:

```
IEnumerable<SpecialtyData> distinctSpecialties = newSpecs.GroupBy(s => s.Name)
                                                         .Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Distinct’s default behavior is a common source of confusion and it’s important to know how to override it.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the default comparison is a reference comparison. It's not looking at the data itself, it's giving you distinct references. Either use your `Select()` to get some value worth comparing or implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your type and pass it to `Distinct`.

Below is a sample implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>`;

```
class SpecialtyDataEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<SpecialtyData>
{
    public bool Equals(SpecialtyData lhs, SpecialtyData rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Name == rhs.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SpecialtyData p)
    {
        return p.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If you did `.Distinct(new SpecialtyDataEqualitComparer())` then you would get items with distinct names. If you want some other definition of equality then change the logic in `Equals` to do the comparisons you require (make related changes to `GetHashCode` so they are consistent, if you do equality by name you shouldn't take the hashcode for some other property).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing custom equality comparers and all that, there is a really nice extension method from MoreLinq - https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/ (by Jon Skeet).

Either download the whole library of MoreLinq, or just add this code below:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(
                            this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{
    var set = new HashSet<TKey>();
    return source.Where(element => set.Add(selector(element)));
}
```

And use it like so:

```
IEnumerable<SpecialtyData> distinctSpecialties = newSpecs
    .Select(s => s).DistinctBy(s => s.Name)
    .OrderBy(s => s.Name);
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I use this A LOT, get very solid performance and don't have to write equality comparers for the 599323 entities I need to run `Distinct` on.

Comment: Tbh - i dont think you even need the select part. Just .DistinctBy. Just a thought tho, should the Func<> be Expression<Func<>> to leverage server side expression tree?.

Comment: Oh and make source IQueryable of course :) (oh and +1 into the bargain!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy` as below

```
IEnumerable<SpecialtyData> distinctSpecialties = 
               newSpecs.GroupBy(s => s.Name).Select(g=> g.First()).OrderBy(s => s.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Distinct() on a custom object (SpecialtyData), you will need to override the two methods Distinct() uses to determine equality.

```
    public override bool Equals(object other) {

    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {

    }
```

Each of these two should return values that define the SpecialtyData objects as unique. In your case it may be as simple as evaluating the 'Name' property.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very nice [post from James Michael Hare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127084/james-michael-hare) that explains why you're getting this results, and I'll quote it here:

> For `Distinct()` (and many other LINQ features) to work, the class being
>   compared (`SpecialtyData` in your example) must implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, or alternatively provide a separate
>   `IEqualityComparer<T>` as an argument to `Distinct()`.
>
> Many LINQ methods take advantage of `GetHashCode()` for performance
>   because internally they will use things like a `Set<T>` to hold the
>   unique items, which uses hashing for O(1) lookups. Also, `GetHashCode()`
>   can quickly tell you if two objects may be equivalent and which ones
>   are definitely not - as long as `GetHashCode()` is properly implemented
>   of course.
>
> So you should make all your classes you intend to compare in LINQ
>   implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` for completeness, or create a
>   separate `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation.

Original post: [This code returns distinct values. However, what I want is to return a strongly typed collection as opposed to an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336275/linq-distinct-c-sharp)

Comment: Yeah, so why not mark this as a duplicate...?

Comment: If you see a duplicate question you should flag/vote to close as a duplicate.  Copying an entire answer is not appropriate.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Unfortunately, that question is not a duplicate.  Although it has the correct answer for this question, the original question is a very specific problem that doesn't much resemble this one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Indeed, perhaps it's rather the other question should be marked as a duplicate of this one then?

Comment: @BartoszKP: That's not true either.

Comment: If there was a way to allow for direct inline mentions of specific (but not exactly duplicated) answers, I'd gladly do so, @Servy. Or, is there one and I'm not aware of? In any case, I appreciate any comments on best practices, so thank you all.

Comment: @OnoSendai: You can post a link to the answer below the question.

Comment: To add to Robert's comment, you should generally prefix the link with something, i.e. "related" or "possible duplicate" or whatever, rather than just a bare link.  If a question *isn't* a duplicate, then it's a sign that the answer of the other question, by itself, probably shouldn't be the answer to this question.  Even if it has most of the information; if the questions aren't dups there's a *very* high probability that it means the answer should be tailored to the new question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, will do so from now on, and with that prefix, Servy. Thanks once again.