# Why we implement GetHashCode in IEqualityComparer?

Tags: c#, equals, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer

I want to get distinct items from `List` in C# by using `IEqualityComparer` interface. But I don't know about `GetHashCode`. I have implement both `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods. And how can I call `Equals` method to get distinct items from a list having user define data type.

Comment: I added a pretty full on answer to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095395/whats-the-role-of-gethashcode-in-the-iequalitycomparert-in-net/4096774#4096774

Comment: possible duplicate of [whats-the-role-of-gethashcode-in-the-iequalitycomparert-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095395/whats-the-role-of-gethashcode-in-the-iequalitycomparert-in-net?lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And how can I call Equals method to get distinct items from a list having user define data type.

Use the [overload of `Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) that takes an `IEqualityComparer` to get the distinct items from a sequence using your custom equality comparer.

> Why we implement GetHashCode in IEqualityComparer?

So that the `IEqualityComparer` can be used as a test for equality in a hash table (hash the items as per the `IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode` method, use `IEqualityComparer.Equals` to check for equality when needed (searching for an item in the hash table, for example).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Distinct` extension method passing it your custom equality comparer.

The reason why you need `GetHashCode()` is that without it you need `O(n^2)` comparisons. With `GetHashCode()` the items can be divided into buckets, which leads to `O(n)` for a good hash implementation.

If the item type is your own, you can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the type itself instead of creating an `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Comment: @JonHanna 1+2+3+...+n-1 = 0.5*n*(n-1) => O(n^2) Not sure how you got O(n!). There are that many edges is a graph with n nodes. You can also easily see that the naive implementation of `Distinct` has two nested loops and no recursion.

Comment: Yes. On consideration, you are completely correct. Indeed, on consideration, I can't even think what on earth made me think it would be O(n!).

Answer (score 0):

> Why we implement GetHashCode in IEqualityComparer?

Because it gets called on IEqualityComparer, usually first, before Equals, at least for the LINQ extension methods which require IEqualityComparer. Otherwise it would be questionable whether you'd really need to implement GetHashCode for determining equality, since you could just use the Equals method for that. Why does LINQ prefer to call GetHashCode? See
[Why use GetHashCode() over Equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305324/why-use-gethashcode-over-equals)